# MySQL - Select specified record with some conditions multiple table

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have a little trouble with a MySQL query, I have two tables tb_user and tb_trx and the last one is the result which I'm trying to do

What I want to do is to show id_user from tb_user which have level = 0 and if id_user in tb_trx have status = 0 more than equals 2, they will not appear in result.

Comment: Can you confirm what you want? Your example output table does not match your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this (N.B. I haven't tested it):

```
select u.id_user from tb_user u
where u.level = 0
and (select count(*) from tb_trx t
     where t.id_user = u.id_user
     and t.status = 0) <= 2
```

Incidentally, I don't think your data set would properly test the rule you have given (which I may have misunderstood, your statement of it is pretty unclear).